# Flask jinja2 renders new line from database field with errors in javascript

Tags: javascript, python, flask, jinja2

I am saving data in Flask application from a textarea.
After saving it I am trying to receive it back to html via javascript like this:

```
const item = "{{item}}";
```

It gives me the following error:
*Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token*

On server side I am just retuning lik this:

```
item = Item.query.filter_by(id=id).first()
item=item.body
```

Error appears only when i save via textarea with a new line.

**How can I fix this?**

So far I tried: this works only if I change from `''` and `""` to template literals ``` `` ```:

```
const item = `{{item}}`;
```

But I am not sure if this method is safe since it makes auto escaping. From jinja2 documentation:
 *"String literals in templates with automatic escaping are considered unsafe because native Python strings are not safe."*

Also `const item = "{{item | safe}}";` seems not helping.

Comment: Did you look at the resulting source code in your browser ?

Comment: it generates code from two lines:

Comment: @Anonymous: <br> var item = "test1
test2"; new line in source code after test1 input, so i guess new line is being generated inside html

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, but using backticks may be the right approach in your case, since they are used in JS for [string litterals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). Another possibility would be to convert the line feeds to `\n` using the available Jinja filters. Also, you could echo back your string to a hidden field in your HTML page, depending on how you intend to use that value.